# Selection rules with no external field?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

According to [The physics of quantum mechanics](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=8d51AQAAQBAJ&dq=binney%20and%20skinner&source=gbs_navlinks_s) By Binney and Skinner (p284) when no external field is applied, we can have:
$$\Delta m=0,\pm 1$$
in any direction. How is this possible considering that the matrix element:
$$\langle n',l',m'|ax+by|n,l,m\rangle$$
is only non-zero if $m'=m\pm 1$ so how com when there is no field applied we can have $$\Delta m=0$$
for a photon travelling in the $z$ direction?

Comment: but what about $\langle \hat Z\rangle$?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform This would correspond to a photon with polarization along its direction of motion. (I am assuming by $\langle \hat Z \rangle$ you mean $\langle n',l',m'|z|n,l,m\rangle$, correct me if I am mistaken).

Comment: See Cohen-Tannoudji, Vol. II, pages 1304-1312 (you can find the book online; the pdf pages are 405-413).

Comment: "If an atom spontaneously emits a photon along z, then m_z has to change" ... that statement sounds correct to me. Are you quite sure that Binney & Skinner are contradicting that statement? They might be talking about photons emitted into any direction...

Comment: Of note:   Mulliken, R.S. 1930. The Interpretation of Band Spectra - Parts I, IIa , IIb. Reviews of Modern Physics, 2, pp. 90 Available from:  http://journals.aps.org/rmp/pdf/10.1103/RevModPhys.2.60